# Como passar valores por referência em Java?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem

Senhores, um dos métodos da classe `Array` tem o método `sort`.

O método `sort` funciona assim:

```
Arrays.sort(vetor);
```

O próprio vetor é alterado, eu procurei em muitos lugares e pelo que entendi isso é passagem de valor por referência.

Em C usamos ponteiros, mas e em Java? Como funciona?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Java, sempre que você usa um parâmetro de um tipo objeto (ou seja, que não é primitivo), o que é passado é uma referência ao objeto (ou seja, não é uma cópia).

Já com tipos primitivos, a passagem ocorre por valor (ou seja, o parâmetro é copiado).

Fazendo uma analogia com C, é como se qualquer variável que não seja de um tipo primitivo, seja na verdade um ponteiro (e é exatamente assim que é implementado pela JVM).

Comment: Mas seria possível passar um valor de tipo primitivo por referência em Java?

Comment: @gato Basta você envelopar ele em uma classe. `public class MeuInt { public int valor; }` e então `public void meuMetodo(MeuInt x) { x.valor = 5; }` - Entretanto, dificilmente você vai fazer algo desse tipo em um código real.

Comment: Eu acho que faz sentido os valores de tipo primitivo não serem passados por referência. Já que você poderia simplesmente retorna um novo valor, porém, se for uma classe com muito dados, ficar retornando novos valores seria mais custoso para a maquina.

Comment: Uma resposta direta. Obrigado, isso explica muita coisa.